# ngForm disable all controls

Tags: html, angular

I would like to disable all controls in a ngForm. Using `<fieldset [disabled]=[true]>` results in a form with disabled controls, but when I set the disabled value to false, the controls are still disabled. I am using Angular and would like to bind the disabling-field to a property if the typescript file. E.g. `<fieldset [disabled]=[MyBindingProp]>`. The binding doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you try `<fieldset [disabled]="MyBindingProp">`?

Comment: You mean "despite the property being false", I guess.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Sorry, I mean indeed disabled is false.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<fieldset [disabled]="MyBindingProp">` like stated in the comments. There's no reason to bind the variable `[MyBindingProp]` with [] unless your passing the variable to another component. Instead, bind it like so, `"MyBindingProp"`. This should allow you to toggle the disablement from your TS file.

Comment: The next line of code doesn't seem to work:     <fieldset [disabled]="!myService.HasStatus">

Comment: @Odrai Why are you trying to bind an object or service? Just create a variable that can be consumed in the HTML and define it as a boolean, if that suits your needs of course